# how can i filter the data of an avl tree

Tags: c++, avl-tree

i got a final homework for my class. The thing is that we need like a file explorer but using trees. I was trying to do it but i got stuck in the sorting (cause we need to sort by size,name,date,etc).

I've created a class called File and im indexing that object. But i realized that i can't sort that tree with the criterion that i want. How can i sort by a specific filter only using that tree (or maybe not) and print all the data (Name,size,date).

```
void BuscarArchivos() {
    string path;
    cout << "Ingrese la ruta: "; //type the path
    cin >> path;

    Archivo * arc2;
    string test;
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
        test = entry.path().string();
        arc2 = new Archivo(test);
        tree->Insert(arc2); //indexing the file class 
    }
}
void ImprimirArchivo()...
```

i want to sort the file tree by a criterion.

Comment: What do you mean by using "filter"?

Comment: Filter is the criterion for sorting

Answer (score 0):

For each criterion, build an AVL tree as an index. Indices are used only to refer to file objects which are stored in other memory locations.

```cpp
using Size = uint64_t;
using Name = std::string;
// using Data = whatever; 

struct Node {
    Size size; // file size
    Name name; // file name
    Data data; // whatever data
    explicit Node(const std::string &path) { /*omitted*/ }
    // construct from path
}

// Tree<Key, Data>
Tree<Size, std::shared_ptr<Node>> indexed_by_size_tree;
Tree<Name, std::shared_ptr<Node>> indexed_by_name_tree;
Tree<Data, std::shared_ptr<Node>> indexed_by_data_tree;

void Build() {
    std::string path;
    std::cin >> path;

    for (const auto &entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
        auto node = std::make_shared<Node>(entry.path().string());
        indexed_by_size_tree.Insert(node->size, node); // size as key
        indexed_by_name_tree.Insert(node->name, node); // name as key
        indexed_by_data_tree.Insert(node->data, node); // data as key
    }
}

void TraverseOrderedBySize() {
    for (auto iter = indexed_by_size_tree.begin();
        iter != indexed_by_data_tree.end(); iter = std::next(iter)) {
        // deal with iter->key
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean as an index?

Comment: It's the exact same meaning as that in DB. If you don't fully understand that, it doesn't matter. You could think of each AVL tree as a sorted array of key-value pairs. And the values are pointers that point to a real record that is not directly stored in the tree. Since there are multiple criterions, you could build an AVL for each criterion (use it as the key to sort). And all balanced trees point to the exact same record memory.

Comment: i think i cant because my tree has recursive functions. is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by recursive functions? I cannot figure out what's the problem.

Comment: i dont know how to use iterators with trees, i manage it recursively. I was trying using overloaded operators but it didnt work